# Error while trying to start MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, eclipse, command-prompt

I have installed mysql as a service and is running.

[image]

But when I try to start mysql I get this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What is the problem? I can't seem to find any relevant solution.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks for the same.

**Edit:**

[image]
Here is my screenshot for the error.

Comment: in your screenshot MySQL is started but can't seen your error message

Comment: Do you want me to add the screenshot for the error in the command prompt as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: @selah1936 I don't think it is. I just installed mysql. And moreover, I haven't even added any database.

Comment: follow the link and find out in the answers section if you can find your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Start the MySQL server instance
$ mysqld --skip-grant-tables

Execute these statements.
$ mysql -u root mysql
$mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('my_password') where USER='root';
$mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;


$ /etc/init.d/mysql restart


$ mysql -u root -p with new password
```

Comment: where do I find the my.cnf??